# Verificar se o elemento existe na ArrayList e, se não, adicioná-lo

Tags: java

eu criei uma classe Estado com nome, sigla e capital e uma Pais com nome, capital e estados - uma ArrayList do tipo Estado.

Quero criar um método insereEstado(Estado e) que antes de adicionar o estado em um Pais, verifica se ele já não foi adicionado antes e exibe uma mensagem. Pensei dessa forma:

```
public void adicionaEstado(Estado e){

    for(int i=0; i < estados.size(); i++){
        if (estados.get(i).getNome().equals(e.getNome())){
           System.out.println("Esse estado já foi adicionado ao país anteriormente.");
        }
        else{
            estados.add(e);
            System.out.println("Estado adicionado.");
        }
    }
}
```

Apesar de não dar erro nenhum, não está adicionando os elementos. Além disso, gostaria de saber como teria que ser a assinatura do método pra eu conseguir retornar essas mensagens.

Comment: `if(estados.contains(e)){...} `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para tu verificar se o item já existe no `ArrayList`, tu podes fazer o seguinte:

```
estados.Contains(e);
```

Para teu método retornar as mensagens que tu está usando, tu deves fazer com o que tipo de retorno do método seja `string` e nāo `void` como estás fazendo atualmente.

Basicamente o método ficaria assim

```
public String adicionaEstado(Estado e){
    if(!estados.Contains(e)){
        estados.add(e);
        return "Estado adicionado.";
    }else{
        return "Esse estado já foi adicionado ao país anteriormente.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Você não precisa percorrer explicitamente toda a lista para verificar a presença de um objeto, `List` já possui um método para isso: [contains(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-).

Então, para usá-lo, basta implementar sua regra de equidade em `Estado`, sobrescrevendo `equals`, algo assim:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Estado)) {
        return false;
    }
    final Estado other = (Estado) obj;
    return this.getNome().equals(other.getNome());
}
```

Na entidade `Pais`, seu método `adicionaEstado` se pareceria com isto:

```
public void adicionaEstado(Estado e) {
    if (estados.contains(e)) {
        System.out.println("Esse estado já foi adicionado ao país anteriormente.");
    } else {
        estados.add(e);
        System.out.println("Estado adicionado.");
    }
}
```

Um exemplo completo seria este:

Entidade `Estado`:

```
public class Estado {

    private String nome;

    // getter e setter

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Estado)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Estado other = (Estado) obj;
        return this.getNome().equals(other.getNome());
    }

}
```

Entidade `Pais`:

```
public class Pais {

    private List<Estado> estados = new ArrayList<>();

    public void adicionaEstado(Estado e) {
        if (estados.contains(e)) {
            System.out.println("Esse estado já foi adicionado ao país anteriormente.");
        } else {
            estados.add(e);
            System.out.println("Estado adicionado.");
        }
    }

}
```

Um programa simples:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Pais pais = new Pais();
        final Estado sc = new Estado();
        sc.setNome("Santa Catarina");

        pais.adicionaEstado(sc);
        pais.adicionaEstado(sc);
    }

}
```

Que gerará esta saída:

```
Estado adicionado.
Esse estado já foi adicionado ao país anteriormente.
```

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais simples seria usando `Contains()`:

```
    if (estados.contains(e))
    {
       System.out.println("Esse estado já foi adicionado ao país anteriormente.");
    }
    else
    {
        estados.add(e);
        System.out.println("Estado adicionado.");
    }
```