# Não consigo atribuir valor a um ArrayList de um Objeto

Tags: java

É o seguinte galera, no meu projeto tenho três classes diferentes, uma é um model (Cliente), uma é a main, que tem um arraylist de Cliente, e outra é uma janela.

Meu intuito é cadastrar os dados digitados na janela no arraylist do objeto, mas não estou conseguindo !

Classe Cliente (model) : Classe normal, com getters e setters de nome, endereço e telefone.

Classe Main :

```
package br.projeto.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import br.projeto.model.Cliente;

public class Main {

    public static ArrayList <Cliente> clienteDB = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //new Principal();
        //new PedidoRapido();
        new Cadastrar();
    }
}
```

Classe Cadastrar (parte que importa [janela]):

```
btnCadastrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Main.clienteDB.setNome("");
            }
        });
```

A questão é que nesse `Main.clienteDB.setNome` só foi colocado ai para exemplificar o que eu quero fazer, pois não estou conseguindo acessar nenhum atributo do objeto Cliente. O que devo fazer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que o que você quer é inserir um novo `Cliente` na lista. Partindo desse pressuposto:

Primeiro, crie o exemplar de `Cliente` e atribua o nome que deseja:

```
Cliente novoCliente = new Cliente();
novoCliente.setNome("Novo cliente");
// setEndereco, setTelefone etc.
```

Depois, insira no fim da lista:

```
Main.clienteDB.add(novoCliente);
```

Comment: Valeu cara ! Era isso mesmo que eu queria, mas e quando eu for por exemplo, pegar algum Cliente desse Array, eu vou digitar `Main.clienteDB.contains(nome do cliente)` ?

Comment: Você quer dizer pegar o objeto Cliente correspondente ao nome?

Comment: Sim ! Por exemplo, se o ArrayList tiver o nome digitado, o programa abre uma janela ... É só pegar o conteúdo digitado e jogar dentro de um `.contains()` ?

Comment: @DanielSantos Dê uma olhada [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82119/26404). Ele dá um exemplo de como fazer. Caso tenha dúvidas, fique à vontade para abrir uma outra pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Main.clienteDB não te devolve Cliente e sim ArrayList.
Pra ter um cliente e poder fazer o que quer você precisa dizer qual cliente deseja `Main.clienteDB.get(0).getNome()`. Obviamente isso vai retornar exceção se sua lista não tiver registro com index 0, ou index que deseja.